# ReceiveBufferSize - Download from Server with High Latency

Tags: vb.net, download, latency

I have a very basic file download that is connecting from the UK to US.  The file is about 10MB and the connection is fast, but the latency is 80ms.

Since we have high latency, is there any way to reduce the acknowledgement window at the TCP layer to reduce the chattiness that occurs?

```
' Download a Large PDF
Using client As New System.Net.WebClient()
    Dim url As String = "doc url"
    Dim beginTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    client.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    client.DownloadFile(url, "TMP.ZIP")
    logWriter.WriteLine("6 MB ZIP File" & "," & (DateTime.Now - beginTime).TotalMilliseconds)
End Using
```

Comment: you are right, I changed it.  been working a lot with both lately

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to reduce the acknowledgement window at the TCP layer to reduce the chattiness that occurs?

On application level you don't have much control over what happens in the network layers of the communication, this is all handled by lower level API's. The .NET framework only provides you with some types that are built on top of these API's to ease the implementation process.

That being said, acknowledgements are what make TCP reliable, these acknowledgements can guarantee that all the data was send to the other side of the connection. You could switch to using UDP, which doesn't use acknowledgements, meaning you could never verify if the data was received successfully, which is great for real-time communication (to balance between speed and quality), but not for sending files, as we want the file to be fully transferred, and not just 96% of the total file. The only way to verify that we received the full file, is to have the receiver notify us that it actually received the packets.

For me this sound like an infrastructure/network architecture related issue. Therefor I personally would not attempt to try and fix this on application level. Using the WebClient class, and thus TCP, feels like the right protocol for your use-case. So in my eyes, you've did your job and implemented the file download correctly.

If you have the possibility, I would try to put a content delivery network (CDN) in between the server and client so that the CDN can offload the down- and upload to an edge server that is close to your physical location.

If this isn't possible you get be creative and, for example, have a second server in the UK that synchronizes itself with the files located on the server in the US. For time/money reasons I wouldn't do this and just take the latency as-is; 80ms is acceptable for me.

Comment: I want to tweak on the application level in order to do further analysis, this looking for a code specific answer rather than infrastructure recommendations

Comment: What is it you want to tweak? You chose HTTP on application layers thus you're stuck with TCP in the transport layers. Unless you revise the protocols used in the application layer, there is not much you can do in code.

Comment: That said, you can ofcourse control some TCP specific settings in Windows. See: DelayedAckFrequency/Timeout of the NetTCPSetting inside the NetTCPIP module. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/set-nettcpsetting?view=win10-ps - but then again, this will handle the problem on system level, not application level. Good luck solving this!